# ASP.Net MVC 4 and .Net 4.5 Project Solution Structure

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5, asp.net-4.5

I have been started working on new enterprise project, platform ASP.Net MVC 4, jQuery, Knockout, .Net 4.5, WCF, Workflow, Business Rules etc, I am trying to find good reference that I can benefit to create solution of entire project. After research myself(Google, stackoverflow and many other blog), below are the solution that I created. However, I am not still sure that I have created is best practice followed and stay next couple of years to adopt newer platform and business changes.

One solution(6 projects)

```
Solution(ProjectName)
  Web(Having MVC 4 project template, added many script reference thru Nuget like      jQuery, knockout etc.,), IOC Container(Castle Windsor)
```

DTO

```
ServiceManager(WCF 4.5)
Core
  Business Rules
  Workflow
  Domain Objects
Common
  Logging - ILog
  Caching - HttpCache
  Security - Custom
DAL
  Repository 
  Unit of Work
  Other Data Base like DB2, Oracle
```

Here is the sequence

`Web Layer --> call to DTO ( Request/Response skelton) --> Service Manager(WCF) --> Core(Business Rules, Workflow flow etc) --> DAL.`

Common project being added across layers.

Please suggest any good design pattern to implement inside and out. For example, efficient way of making Web calls to services, kind of proxy channel, distributed transaction, connecting different data source.

Right now I do have 2 different data base, one is SQL Serer and other one DB2 hosted one mainframe. DAL project I added EF to handle SQL based transaction. And DB2 I added OLEDB thin driver. I need some design pattern how to route the caller based on request to different source.

Also I need some good suggestion about Dependency Injection and IOC framework. I have been decided to use castle windsor( I have looked at NInjuct, Spring.Net, Autofac) but still uncertain about drawbacks.

Thanks lot for your guidance and suggestion on this tag.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I wouldn't create that many layers from the start. I'd say start with something basic and then expand as you go.

There's no real one best practice, everything depends on your project. In general though, I find it easier to add a layer when needed, then to remove a layer afterwards. If you see yourself making calls that simply pass through a layer you have a good indication that you have too many layers.

As for dependency injection, you can use either one of the containers you mention, they all have similar features. Personally I prefer Ninject, but that's a matter of taste. One drawback that you can have with a DI container is that it may become a bit harder to navigate your code, because of the loose coupling (if you're using it correctly). Resharper helps a lot with that.

From what I can see you have a very thick service layer which holds all the domain logic and besides that a lot of classes which only have properties (the common project across all layers). This is what's called an anemic model and by some seen as an anti-pattern (although it often does the job just fine). An alternative approach is DDD, where you model behavior and state on the same classes. In my opinion this works best if you also apply CQRS. (Command Query Responsibility Segregation)

If you're interested in such an approach, I wrote an [Introduction to DDD, CQRS and Event Sourcing](http://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2013/12/05/introduction-to-domain-driven-design-cqrs-and-event-sourcing/), which you can check out. For more information also check everything from Greg Young and Udi Dahan

Comment: Thanks for you comments. The reason being used thick service layer, in future if they decided to go far any open source based view engine, and core business object can be reused by WCF service means or REST based service. I understand I am putting most of plumbing work under neath of services. This is one of the requirement from client. Please suggest.

Comment: It shouldn't be a requirement from the client. A client should not be concerned with the architecture, only with functionality. If he still is, it's your task to tell him what the right architecture is for his needs. As I said, don't develop for the future, develop for the things you need now. If in the future you need to put in another view engine, you can still pull out a layer. It will be easier, because you'll know what should be abstracted and what not. If you start abstracting now, you may be abstracting the wrong things and end up with an extra layer with no value

Comment: That make sense. Do you have any suggestion of making service call from model class. I mean create proxy channel and pass the object. I would like set some pattern on code so that my development team can follow the guidelines, if any web development team wants to call service, there is no adding end point thru visual studio. Let me know if you got any good design for consume and call service manager.

Comment: Your model classes shouldn't be concerned with calling services. Your model should solve business problems, workflows, ... Your WCF is just an implementation detail. You should put that inside your  infrastructure code or something similar.